# Is it safe enough to store a file in the TEMP directory

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it safe enough to store a file in the %TEMP% directory via `GetTempPath`, `GetTempPath` and `CreateFile` for more than two hours? Is there any guarantees that this file won't be deleted earlier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no guarantees, however you could permission it to deny delete (or just set the 'read only' attribute) to make it more likely it survives.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That is a bad idea.

It all really depends on your definition of 'safe enough'. If you store the launch codes for a nuclear device, it might not be safe enough. If you just store some cached data that can be rebuilt if it's deleted, sure it is safe enough.

Comment: @MarkJansen If you have the launch codes for a nuclear device I wouldn't store them in %TEMP%, just a thought...

Answer (score 2):

A file you create in the TEMP directory must be created with the CreateFile's `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option.  This ensures that the file will *always* be cleaned-up and you cannot spray garbage files, even if your program crashes before it has a chance to delete the file again.

This option then also inevitably forces you to do the Right Thing, keeping the file opened while you are using it.  Which in turn prevents anybody from the deleting the file, even if they use a sledge-hammer.

Lots of programs don't follow this advice and a user's TEMP directory tends to be a big olde mess, forcing the user to clean it up manually once in a while.  A built-in feature of Windows, he'll use the "Disk Cleanup" applet.  The kind of scenario where you will lose the file if you don't follow this advice.  Best to use %AppData% instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees. This folder is usually not cleared except the user starts any cleanup.

But everyone can delete files here. And it is wise to do that on a regular base

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the file from being deleted, you can keep a handle open (assuming the application is running the whole time) and do **not** specify `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` (and, if applicable, neither `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`).

Alternative:

Use a path in %APPDATA% or  %PROGRAMDATA% that you clear yourself regulary, or let the user specify a path.

In addition, you could register a scheduled task to clean the folder regulary.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want that another process can delete your files, just keep them open with a share mode of `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. That way any attempt to delete them will fail, but any other process will be able to read or write them.

BTW : this is not related with the files living in %TEMP% folder.

If you cannot have a process to keep them open all the time, you must rely on other processes (and other users) on your system not doing anything ...